# Share printer across VLAN separated networks using HP 1810-48G Switch (J9660A)

Tags: networking

I am setting up 4 Vlan.Port 1 is my management port and belongs to Vlan 1 Port 2-12 is Vlan 2. Port 13-24 is Vlan 3. Port 25-36 Vlan 4. There is 3 different companies that uses Vlan 2-4 but i want them to share one printer. The printer is connected to port 48.

Will this work or do i need to have to install a router?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you have split your switch into 3 virtual switches. In order to move traffic between the switches you will need a router.

Another option would be to get a print server that can have several virtual interfaces on a single physical NIC. For instance, any linux box with a gigabit NIC and CUPS will do.

Note that in any case you will have to ensure that the 3 networks use different IP subnets, otherwise routing would not work.

A print server with 3 virtual interfaces would have different IP addresses one for each network. It will be plugged into say port 37 that will be configured into vlan 2,3,4 tagged.

Comment: The Cisco term is "Inter-VLAN Routing".  You need a router or a layer 3 switch.

Comment: @MikeChristiansen thank you, that's interesting. Since ProCurve switches only support 802.1Q VLANs there is not much difference between VLAN and physical network routing.

Comment: There is not much difference between Inter-VLAN routing and physical network routing with Cisco either.  With a Cisco router, you just create multiple logical ports (each with their own VLAN) for one physical port.  Then, the router will route, as normal, for the directly connected virtual ports.